# An intuitive way of using <? syntax on any include page within a Google Apps Script projects

Tags: google-apps-script

Within Google Apps Script projects in general, it feels like its necessary to initialize and return `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("<the page name>")` in order to use `<?` on "that" given page.

Within my code.js file, is my following doGet() function. The below code allows me to use `<?` variable syntax on my main page labeled as **mpage.html** :

```js
function doGet(e) {
  // Logger.log(e.paramter);
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("mpage");
  tmp.title = "My Custom Title";
  return tmp.evaluate();
}
```

That allows me to do something like this on mpage.html :

```html
  <header>
    <p>custom header content</p>
     <h1><?= title; ?></h1>
  </header>
```

When I deploy my web app, I can see `<h1>My Custom Title</h1>` on the front-end of my app.

But if I were to also place `<?!= include("page-body"); ?>` on my mpage.html and have a page called page-body.html, how can I extend my `doGet(e) {}` function so that I can use `<?` variable syntax on mpage.html, **and** page-body.html, **and also any** other include file added to mpage.html?

In detail below are my files :

#### mpage.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <?!= include("page-css"); ?>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <p>the below variable renders successfully on the front end of my web app</p>
        <h1><?= title; ?></h1>
    </header>

    <?!= include("page-body"); ?>

    <footer>
        <p>custom footer content</p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

#### page-body.html

```html
<main>
    <p>how can I render another variable like this, from this page?</p>
    <h3><?= other-var; ?></h3>
</main>
```

#### code.js file

```js
function doGet(e) {
  // Logger.log(e.paramter);
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("mpage");
  tmp.title = "My Custom Title";
  return tmp.evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

Comment: If my understanding of your question is correct, I think that in your situation, in order to retrieve the evaluated HTML content, it is required to use `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile` in the function `include`. But, I cannot know your actual script. So, can you provide your current script of `include` and `page-body.html`?

Comment: Thank you for providing it. I will check it.

Comment: Can you provide the function `include`?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your question, I thought that in your situation, it is required to use `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile` in the function `include`.
- And, I'm worried that `<h3><?= other-var; ?></h3>` might be modified to other variable. For example, it's `<h3><?= other_var ?></h3>`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### Google Apps Script side:

Please modify `include` as follows.

```js
function include(filename) {
  if (filename == "page-body") {
    const html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename);
    html["other_text"] = "sample text";
    return html.evaluate().getContent();
  }
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

##### HTML side:

Please modify `page-body.html` as follows.

```html
<main>
  <p>how can I render another variable like this?</p>
  <h3><?= other_text ?></h3>
</main>
```

#### Note;

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: I agree with your bullet points. What modifications would need to be made to my doGet() function? Also what if I had "page-<other>" in addition to "page-body". do I have to repeat the coding processes for every include?

Comment: @klewis Thank you for replying. About `What modifications would need to be made to my doGet() function?`, in this case, I think that it is not required to modify your `doGet`.

Comment: @klewis When `mpage.html` is loaded, in the case of `<?!= include("page-body"); ?>`, `include("page-body")` is evaluated and `html["other_text"] = "sample text";` is reflected in `page-body`. By this, `doGet` returns the evaluated HTML of `mpage.html`. If my explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: That's very helpful.  But what If I also had `<?!= include("page-body2"); ?>` in addition to my code.  How can we keep the function include(filename) {} DRY ?

Comment: This was the initial step I needed!  This now will help me find out how to improve the include function, to allow multiple pages to return `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename);`  Many thanks!

Comment: @klewis Thank you for replying. About `But what If I also had <?!= include("page-body2"); ?> in addition to my code.`, in that case, if you want to reflect other values, how about modifying `include` like `else if (filename == "page-body2") {,,,}`?